# Python Path - current dir automatically added?

Tags: python-3.x, import, sys.path

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6.

I played around with sys.path and more specifically adding stuff.
However I'm no 'stuck' in a sense that the current directory is now automatically added as the first element to sys.path

```
import sys
for i in sys.path:
   print(i)
```

yields first "", and then always the current directory, no matter what folder I'm in. (and of course the 'default' libraries)

This is actually quiet handy, however I don't seem to be able to remove again.

And as this is not added on the servers I'm working on, it becomes really hard to transfer my code to servers...

Any help?

## Clarification:

So when I do :

```
import sys
for i in sys.path:
    print(i)
```

I get:

```
/home/XXXX
/usr/lib/python36.zip
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/home/XXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

The first is the current directory from where I start python3, in this case in my home directory.

```
/home/XXXX/Downloads
/usr/lib/python36.zip
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/home/XXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

When run from my Downloads folder.

On my server I get:

```
/usr/lib/python36.zip
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Which seems better?
Well in certain cases (lots of local modules the first is sometimes handy). Anyway I want to switch it off. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to rephrase, its really hard to tell what you are looking for. Maybe an example might help.

Comment: Did you by any chance set something to this effect in somewhere like `.pythonstartup` in your home directory?